# How can I set the permission like r_emailaddress and r_fullprofile in linked in application

Tags: linkedin-api

I want **LinkedIn** profile fields of the user like *firstname,lastname,phone & emailId*. But with **r_liteprofile** it is not giving me the *phone_no and email*. So, how can I set the  **r_basicprofile** or **r_fullprofile**. So, i get it directly in my site with new updated version of API.

As I am using the below API endpoint

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me/~?oauth2_access_token=".json_decode($server_output)->access_token."&format=json");

Answer (score 0):

just add it as param to your request 
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me/~?oauth2_access_token=XXXXXXXXXX&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social

you can find more info in the documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/marketing/context